# Expression Blend 4.0 - What layer effects and blend modes are supported for imported Photoshop files?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, import, expression-blend, photoshop

Many Photoshop effects aren't property supported by Expression Blend.  Usually I see an option to "flatten layer" to get around this problem.  Is there a comprehensive list of what effects or blend modes are supported by Blend?  I'm curious about the Silverlight features supported during import but would also like to know if there are any differences for WPF.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight and wpf (afaik) support only one standard blend mode. You could implement your own blend mode using pixel shaders, but it is pretty painfull process.